# Getting error "No package 'libffi' found" when installing python-telegram-bot

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, python-telegram-bot

I tried to install python-telegram-bot on my raspberry pi but I got this problem:

```
Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-QLuRQr/cffi/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-1vjudm-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=:
    Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'libffi' found
    Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'libffi' found
    Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'libffi' found
    ...
    arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-Ub3vap/python2.7-2.7.13=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -DUSE__THREAD -DHAVE_SYNC_SYNCHRONIZE -I/usr/include/ffi -I/usr/include/libffi -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c c/_cffi_backend.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/c/_cffi_backend.o
    c/_cffi_backend.c:15:17: fatal error: ffi.h: No such file or directory
     #include <ffi.h>
                     ^
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-QLuRQr/cffi/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-1vjudm-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user --prefix=" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-QLuRQr/cffi/
```

I tried this command but I got the same problem:

```
pip install python-telegram-bot==12.0.0b1 --upgrade 
pip install python-telegram-bot --upgrade
python -m pip install python-telegram-bot
```

Comment: Is that the _entire_ error message? Can you check again to see if there are more error messages.

Comment: i could not to share entire message here so i add it to google document here :
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1sADIAsPawNX7I-7QI8jf5yaA844s3WZrHDOYsKmfiRk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: What OS are you using? Are you using Raspbian Stretch?

Comment: yes its raspbian-stretch-full

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems the main problem is this:

```
  Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
  Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
  to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
  No package 'libffi' found
```

That Python package you are installing requires CFFI which requires `libffi`.

Try installing `libffi` first:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install libffi-dev
```

If you are on a non-standard OS (not Raspbian) that you can't use `apt`, you can manually download and install the `libffi-dev` files directly from [Debian](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/libffi-dev) or build it on your own from [OpenEmbedded](http://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/branch/master/recipes/?q=libffi).